# URI in source code

Tags: c++

Any anyone explain why I can put URIs in C++ source code?

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    using namespace std;
    http://www.google.com
    int x = 5;
    cout << x;
}
```

This seems strange to me?

For example Visual Studio 2015 gives me a warning: warning C4102: 'http': unreferenced label
but the code compiles!

Comment: It thinks its a label + comment. Lookup C++ `goto` statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler sees `http:` as a label, and `//www.google.com` as a comment.